# Iteration vs Recursion: Calculate point position in sequence for known iteration

Tags: javascript, math, recursion, iteration, sequence

I have a recursive function that takes a point `{x,y}` and calculates the next point in the sequence, recursively.

It looks a little like this:

```
var DECAY = 0.75;
var LENGTH = 150;
var ANGLE = 0.52;

getNextPoint(0, 0, ANGLE, LENGTH);

function getNextPoint (x, y, a, l) {

    l *= DECAY;
    a += ANGLE; 

    var x1 = x - Math.cos(a) * l;
    var y1 = y - Math.sin(a) * l;

    //We now have 2 points, draw lines etc.

    getNextPoint(x1, y1, a, l); 
}
```

How can I calculate a point (or 2 consecutive points) given a known iteration?

I know that the angle and length values for a given iteration could be calculated fairly easily with something like the following:

```
var a = ANGLE * iteration;
var l = LENGTH * Math.pow(DECAY, iteration);
```

But I would still need to know the position of the point at `iteration - 1` to apply these values to?

Comment: A recursion should have a base case where it stops (you cannot create strict infinite sequences in js)?

Comment: The above is a simplified version of my existing function - it is merely representative. I'm not looking for comments on the validity of the recursion, but rather help in getting point values for a known iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. Aren't `x1/y1` the point values in your sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of this as complex numbers. `z = x + i*y` is your point. `b = cos(a)*l + i*sin(a)*l` is some parameter, and `c = cos(ANGLE)*DECAY + i*sin(ANGLE)*DECAY` is a constant.

Initially you have `z0 = 0` and `b0 = c*LENGTH/DECAY`. In each recursion you do

```
b(k+1) = b(k)*c
z(k+1) = z(k) - b
```

So you have

```
b1 = b0*c  = c^2*LENGTH/DECAY
z1 = z0-b1 = -b1 = -c^2*LENGTH/DECAY
b2 = b1*c  = c^3*LENGTH/DECAY
z2 = z1-b2 = -(c^2+c^3)*LENGTH/DECAY
⋮
zn = -(c^2+c^3+⋯+c^(n+1))*LENGTH/DECAY
```

If you [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20c%5E%28k%2B1%29%20for%20k%20from%201%20to%20n) it will tell you that

```
c^2+c^3+⋯+c^(n+1) = c^2*(c^n - 1)/(c - 1)
```

You can make the denominator real if you multiply by the complex conjugate. Then you can turn the whole thing back into a formula for real numbers. So let's write

```
c = cr + i*ci        cr = cos(ANGLE)*DECAY  ci = sin(ANGLE)*DECAY
d = c^n = dr + i*di  dr = cos(n*ANGLE)*pow(DECAY, n)  di = …
```

Then we have

```
  c^2*(d - 1)*(cr - i*ci - 1)/((cr + i*ci - 1)*(cr - i*ci - 1))
= ((cr + i*ci)*(cr + i*ci)*(dr + i*di - 1)*(cr - i*ci - 1)) /
  ((cr - 1)*(cr - 1)*ci*ci)
= ((cr^3*dr + cr*ci^2*dr - cr^2*ci*di - ci^3*di - cr^3 - cr*ci^2
    - cr^2*dr + ci^2*dr + 2*cr*ci*di + cr^2 - ci^2) +
   (cr^2*ci*dr + ci^3*dr + cr^3*di + cr*ci^2*di - cr^2*ci - ci^3
    - 2*cr*ci*dr - cr^2*di + ci^2*di + 2*cr*ci))/((cr - 1)*(cr - 1)*ci*ci)

xn = -(cr^3*dr + cr*ci^2*dr - cr^2*ci*di - ci^3*di - cr^3 - cr*ci^2
       - cr^2*dr + ci^2*dr + 2*cr*ci*di + cr^2 - ci^2) /
      ((cr - 1)*(cr - 1)*ci*ci) * LENGTH / DECAY
yn = -(cr^2*ci*dr + ci^3*dr + cr^3*di + cr*ci^2*di - cr^2*ci - ci^3
       - 2*cr*ci*dr - cr^2*di + ci^2*di + 2*cr*ci) /
      ((cr - 1)*(cr - 1)*ci*ci) * LENGTH / DECAY
```

The expansions of the numerator came out of my CAS; it might well be that you can write this somewhat shorter, but I don't feel like multiplying those four terms manually just to try that.

Here is a working example to demonstrate all of this:

```js
var ctxt = document.getElementById("MvG1").getContext("2d");
var sin = Math.sin, cos = Math.cos, pow = Math.pow;

var DECAY = 0.75;
var LENGTH = 150;
var ANGLE = 0.52;

var cr = cos(ANGLE)*DECAY, ci = sin(ANGLE)*DECAY;
var cr2 = cr*cr, ci2 = ci*ci, cr3 = cr2*cr, ci3 = ci2*ci;
var f = - LENGTH / DECAY / ((cr - 1)*(cr - 1)*ci*ci)

ctxt.beginPath();
ctxt.moveTo(100,450);

for (var n = 0; n < 20; ++n) {
  var da = pow(DECAY, n), dr = cos(n*ANGLE)*da, di = sin(n*ANGLE)*da;
  var xn, yn;
  xn = (cr3*dr + cr*ci2*dr - cr2*ci*di - ci3*di - cr3 - cr*ci2
        - cr2*dr + ci2*dr + 2*cr*ci*di + cr2 - ci2)*f;
  yn = (cr2*ci*dr + ci3*dr + cr3*di + cr*ci2*di - cr2*ci - ci3
        - 2*cr*ci*dr - cr2*di + ci2*di + 2*cr*ci)*f;
  console.log([xn,yn]);
  ctxt.lineTo(0.1*xn + 100, 0.1*yn + 450);
}

ctxt.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="MvG1" width="300" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Amazing answer ! A smoother answer using for (var n = 0; n < 10; n+=0.1) {

Comment: Thanks, my experience with complex numbers is essentially zero, so the example is much appreciated!